# Test purchases not showing up in Google Wallet Merchant Center

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-pay

Recently implemented in-app billing for my app and everything *seems* to be working fine.

Followed the instructions in [Testing in-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html), used the `android.test.purchased` id to simulate the purchase.

Reason I say *seems* to work is because the purchase flow works fine, pops up the dialog, shows 'payment successful' and able to query the inventory after purchase etc

However, I do not see any orders listed in my Google Wallet Merchant Centre. I noticed this, because I wanted to cancel an order to re-test the purchase.

The [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#cancelling) implies that test purchases will be listed and you can cancel manually:

> **Cancelling completed test purchases**
>   Cancel purchases manually—you can go to the Google Wallet Merchant Center, look up the
>   transaction, and then cancel it. You can find transactions by looking
>   up their order numbers.

Also, I've noticed that when setting up the `IabHelper` it doesn't matter if I put in my Base64-encoded public key, or a random string, the `IabHelper` always successfully starts up. For example, the following works:

```
mIabHelper = new IabHelper(this, "this-can-be-any-string");
```

Despite the transaction flow seemingly working properly, given the two points:

- No transactions visible in Google Wallet Merchant Centre
- `IabHelper` is indifferent to a random string vs my public key

I am wondering if I've done something wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions/know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchases will not be listed on your developer console, when you use the IDs

```
android.test.purchased
android.test.refunded
android.test.cancelled.
```

These are product IDs for **static responses**, used to only simulate the testing, during early stages of development. For testing your app with **real-time test purchases**, you might want to do things that are suggested  in the section `Setting Up for Test Purchases` of your link and [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Test your public key relevance when you tryout the real test purchase. It is more likely that the IABHelper is indifferent only incase of static testing.  Ideally, you should get a 'Signature Mismatch Error' when the public Keys don't match.

Comment: Ah yes, the docs were just quite confusing. The order it was written in, made me think that the option to Cancel was for the static purchases (somehow I had classified static purchases as the 'Sandbox')